# Gauss's Original Gaussian Distribution Proof Help

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

I am refering to the proof of the guassian from the famous document: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Allendoerfer/stahl96.pdf

I have attached the pictures below of the proof.

The proof starts on pg 105. I was unable to understand on pg 106 how this step took place

> M2 =M3 =···=Mn =M−nN

Why are all the observations set to the same value? It just doesnt make any sense, this will never happen in real life. But this is a general proof so there must be something I am missing. [Someone told me that they are not really equal but the statement is saying they can be expressed in that form,however this does not seem so to me]

Here are the assumptions used in the proof:

> Gauss explained that he used the least squares criterion to locate the
>   orbit that best fit the observations [12]. This criterion was
>   justified by a theory of errors that was based on the following three
>   assumptions:
>
> 1. Small errors are more likely than large errors.
> 2. For any real number ε the likelihood of errors of magnitudes ε and −ε are equal.
> 3. In the presence of several measurements of the same
>      quantity, the most likely value  of the quantity being measured is
>      their average.

Here is the proof:
[image: proof1]
[image]

Comment: The form of $f$ is true for any set of $M_i$ values. The development up to that point holds for any values of the $M_i$. If a convenient choice is made for those (without loss of generality), the form of $f$ must nevertheless still hold; this is what was done.

Comment: @Glen_b Yeah, but it's a little weird though that $f(x)=kx$ is seemingly only established for the convenient choice of M.  The argument is not clear that the form of $f(x)$ will be the same for any M. Perhaps the "well-known exercise" is not so well known anymore that produces the wlog argument.

Comment: @Glen_b I do not agree, there can be a general form and a more simplified form for special cases. This appears to be the latter. And how can you say "without loss of generality", by setting so many observations to equal, definitely seems like generality is lost....

Comment: @Glen_b is correct.  A simple example of this kind of argument might drive the point home.  Suppose we have a function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ that is known to be constant.  To find its value, we are free to plug in *any* vector we wish to evaluate it.  I hope this claim is not controversial!  Now let $$g(M_1,\ldots,M_n) = f(M_1-\bar M) + f(M_2-\bar M) +\cdots + f(M_n-\bar M)$$ and apply the foregoing observation.